# Understanding Equivalence relation on a universal set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I was giving this following problem as a challenge problem, and am having a hard time understanding where to begin.

Let R be the relation on a universal set U defined by A R B if, and only if, A∆B=∅. Prove that this is an equivalence relation and describe the set of equivalence classes of R.

I'm visualizing the relation between A and B as an arrow diagram going from A to B, but can't wrap my head around how this is an equivalence relation. Any clarification on how to set this up would be appreciated.

Comment: Verify that the relation is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.  As a hint, you should recognize this relation by a different name and by a different defining property... What can you say about $A$ compared to $B$ if you know that $A\triangle B = \emptyset$?  Are there any elements of $A$ that are not elements of $B$?  Are there any elements of $B$ that are not elements of $A$?

Comment: As for describing the equivalence classes... if you describe your equivalence relation in this other way then you should be able to have an easier time doing so.  What other sets, if any, might $A$ be related to?  It will be related to itself, what else?

Comment: So if A△B=∅, there are no elements that are exclusive to A or B. This would mean that A and B are the same set. From there it should be pretty simple to describe the equivalence as they would be the exact same set.

Comment: Precisely.$~~~$